# Combine aggregates at different levels of detail in R

Tags: r

I have a table of employment by city and industry

```
df <- read.table(text="city industry emp
Washington Auto 2
Washington Aero 2
Boston Auto 4
Boston Aero 2", header = TRUE)
```

I want to calculate a Relative Diversity Index by city, i.e. the sum for each
city, over all industries, of the absolute value of the difference between each industry’s share in local employment and its share in national employment. The math looks like this: RDIc = 1/∑i|Sci-Si| (small letters are subscripts: c for city and i for industry; RDI is the index; S means share).

Using the above data, I should get:

```
city       rdi
Washington   5
Boston     7.5
```

Because:

- RDI Washington = 1/(abs(2/4-6/10)+abs(2/4-4/10)) = 5
- RDI Boston = 1/(abs(4/6-6/10)+abs(2/6-4/10)) = 7.5

Of course, this is mock data and I have 100s of cities and industries. I haven't been able to do this in R, even in multiple steps, short of splitting the df by city and then reassembling it, which seems very clunky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of little steps, but this works

```
library(dplyr)
natl = df %>%
    mutate(ind_total = sum(emp)) %>%
    group_by(industry) %>%
    summarize(si = sum(emp) / first(ind_total)) %>%
    select(industry, si)

result = df %>%
    group_by(city) %>%
    mutate(sci = emp / sum(emp)) %>%
    inner_join(natl) %>%
    group_by(city) %>%
    summarize(rdi = 1 / sum(abs(sci - si)))

result
# # A tibble: 2 × 2
#         city   rdi
#       <fctr> <dbl>
# 1     Boston   7.5
# 2 Washington   5.0
```

Answer (score 3):

This answer is based on the nice answer by @Gregor. I have just tried to reduce the steps so you don't need to create another data.frame and then join it

```
df1 <- df %>% 
  mutate(ind_total = sum(emp)) %>% 
  group_by(industry) %>% 
  mutate(si = sum(emp) / first(ind_total)) %>% 
  group_by(city) %>% 
  mutate(sci = emp / sum(emp)) %>% 
  summarise(rdi = 1 / sum(abs(sci - si)))

> df1
# A tibble: 2 × 2
        city   rdi
      <fctr> <dbl>
1     Boston   7.5
2 Washington   5.0
```

Comment: Lol - I scrolled down enough that I only saw the top of your code and missed the note at the top. I was getting annoyed thinking you had copied my answer - scroll up to see your nice comment and just laugh.

Comment: :-) 

Thanks for your nice answer. I learnt alot from it. Honestly, I wouldn't consider mine as an answer. I think more of it as a comment but when I write it as a comment it is not nicely formatted as the answer.

Comment: I think you could omit the `ungroup`, since you change the grouping on the next line anyway.